# Installing a node package

Tags: node.js

I want to style up my website and found a nice package for animations that only start when on screen view. The installation has to be done with node npm . I'm new to this and can't get it done. Please help

the packages website is: http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

and the error message I get when installing it is:

```
C:\Users\sam>npm install aos --save
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sam\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sam\package.json'
npm WARN sam No description
npm WARN sam No repository field.
npm WARN sam No README data
npm WARN sam No license field.

+ aos@2.2.0
added 4 packages in 3.053s

C:\Users\sam>c
```

Comment: <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script> you can try using this to CDNs.

Comment: The command is correct. But the issue seems to be with the folder structure you have. It says that it cannot find the package.json file. You will have to run a npm init first. This will create a package.json file in your directory.

Comment: Your using powershell (Windows terminal), the syntax is different for bash and powershell I personally don't know how but you can look it up with a google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use it for an animation purpose in your webpage then I would suggest going with the CDN rather than keeping dependency in your package file.

Add this scripts in your head tag in html or any template file you are using

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and add its js where you have included your all other js files like jquery and all.

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have node installed:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

This is how you install it via npm:

`npm install aos --save`

If you already have it as a dependency you can use:

`npm install`

That will install all missing dependency

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

You can import these 2 CDN links and try.

> Option 2 : **Go to your project directory** then run

`npm init`

Then it will ask you for details about your project add those details and then run.

`npm install aos --save`

This should work.

Comment: He said it has to be done with npm so this answer is redundant might be a better idea to leave a comment asking if he is able to use CDN links

Comment: No problem, just thought I should point that out in case you get down votes